# Why are there skew lines in projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So if I have the space $\mathbb{P}^3$, then I have seen in many resources that I can have skew lines, i.e. lines that do not intersect. However, I thought that this would contradict Bezout's theorem, because any two lines must intersect in projective space. What am I missing?

Comment: Space != plane.

Comment: Three planes in dimension $4$ may  very well intersect only at the origin.

Comment: Consider $L = \{ (x,y,0,0) \} $ and $L' = \{ (0,0,x,y) \}$ which have no intersection.

Comment: Please read about Clifford parallel lines. The fact is that two lines intersect in projective **plane**, not space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a consequence of the Bezout's theorem we can say that two straight lines **in a plane** that does not have infinitely common points have one common point that can be a point at infinity. But this is true only if the two lines are **in the same plane** because [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem) refers to plane curves in the same plane . In the space ve can have two lines in different planes.

Comment: Ok thank you there was a confusion about the statement of Bezout's theorem